# Regarding Administrative Distance

Tags: routing, router, bgp, administrative-distance, vendor

Different vendors use different Administrative distance for the same protocol.For example, in a Cisco router, the `eBGP`, AD value is 20, whereas in Arista routers, it appears different(i believe, 200).

What is the thought process behind this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Administrative distance is local to a router. AD is used simply to break a tie when different routing protocols have the same route. You cannot compare metrics between the routing protocols, so some method is needed to determine which route should be placed in the routing table. Cisco created AD for this, and other vendors have something similar. Each vendor determines which routing protocol is most "trustworthy," and that is the route that is placed in the routing table.

Cisco has determined that eBGP (AD 20) is very trustworthy, while iBGP (AD 200) is not. That is a purely Cisco determination, and it is local to the router and its routing table. Other vendors have their own ideas about how to break a tie when multiple routing protocols come up with the same route. Some copy Cisco, and some have other ideas about how to rank routing protocols, but it is up to each vendor to determine this because there is no independent standard.

Answer (score 0):

Administration value (AD) is nothing to be considered in border perspective of networks . AD value operation is limited with specific router configuration itself ..

When multiple routing protocols are configured in router with route pointing to same destination . In this case router will make desicion to choose route among multiple route with different protocols based on least AD value . We have feasibility to  change AD value   according to our requirement to priorities routing protocols usage in layer3 device .